# d3 v4 aplicar zoom al centro

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, zoom

Estoy intentando buscar un equivalente al `d3.behavior.zoom()` de la version v3 de d3.js. Pero hasta ahora no he podido encontrar nada.

Lo que busco es poder hacer `.center([width / 2, height / 2])`, es decir, que el zoom se aplique siempre al centro del grafico y no hacia la posicion del raton.

Me gustaria saber si hay algun equivalente en la v4 ya que han eliminado esta funcionalidad.

#### Editado

Os dejo el codigo del zoom que yo tengo hecho, este funciona, pero se aplica al centro sino a la posicion del raton.

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()                            
                .scaleExtent([1, 40])
                .translateExtent([[-100, -100], [w + 90, h + 100]])
                .on("zoom", zoomed);

            svg.call(zoom);
            function zoomed() {
                var posicionIni = w/2;              
                svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
                gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)));
                gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale)));        
                grupo2.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
                grupoLineas.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
                grupo.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);

            }   
            d3.select("#botonZoom")
                .on("click", resetted);
            function resetted() {
              svg.transition()
                  .duration(750)
                  .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
            }
```

Os dejo el resto del codigo de como creo el grafico:

```
//-----------------------------------Variables ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //Alto y ancho
            var w = 500;
            var h = 500;
            var padding = 0;
            var coundata= 0;
            var maxx = 0.30
            var minx = -0.30
            var maxy = 6
            var miny = -6


//-----------------------------------CREAR GRAFICO SCATTER ----------------------------------------------------------------
            //Funciones de escala
            var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                 .domain([minx, maxx])
                                 .range([padding, h]);

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                 .domain([miny, maxy])
                                 .range([h, padding]);

            var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                 .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                                 .range([2, 6]);

            //Eje x
            var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                .scale(xScale);;

            //Eje y
            var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                .scale(yScale);

            //Crear el elemento svg
            var svg = d3.select("#linegraph")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Colores
            grupo = svg.append("svg:g");

            var c2 = grupo.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+w/2+","+padding+")")
                .attr("fill", "green");

            var c1 = grupo.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+","+padding+")")
                .attr("fill", "yellow");


            var c3 = grupo.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+","+h/2+")")
                .attr("fill", "red");

            var c4 = grupo.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (w/2) - padding)             
                .attr("height", (h/2)- padding)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+w/2+","+h/2+")")
                .attr("fill", "orange");


            var g =svg.append("g");

            //Añadimos el eje x
            var gX = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h/2) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            //Añadimos el eje y
            var gY = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2)  + ",0)")
                .call(yAxis);

            nowData = []
            var grupo2 = svg.append("svg:g");


            //Creamos los puntos
            var datos = grupo2.selectAll("circle")
               .data(nowData)
               .enter()            
               .append("circle")                           
               .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d[0]);
               })
               .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[1]);
               })
               .attr("r", function(d) {
                    return 5;
               })
                .append("svg:title") 
                    .text(function(d) {return "Valor x: "+d[0] +"\n Valor y :"+d[1]; })                     

               ;
```

#### Edicion 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script src="datos_puntos.json"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

            .axis path,
            .axis line {
                fill: none;
                stroke: black;
                shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }

            .axis text {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 11px;
            }

        </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="linegraph"></div>
        <button id="botonZoom"> Reset </button>
        <button class="play">play</button>
        <button class="pause" disabled>pause</button>
        <button class="stop" disabled>stop</button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="eae" > eaepunt1
        <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="arab" > arabpunt1
        <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="planned_checked" > Cola
        <input style="width:10px" value="1" type="numeric" name="tamanio_cola" id="tamanio_cola"/>Tamaño cola
<script>

 ///Aqui esta el codigo de arriba
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

#### Edicion 3

He conseguido un ejemplo, con el zoom funcionando como yo quiero, pero no consigo aplicarlo a mi script. Aqui el [ejemplo](https://embed.plnkr.co/kVw0rWMo728dmbm8EjuG/).

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo y elemento sobre el que quieras el zoom?

Comment: @lois6b Claro, la cosa es que el zoom ya funciona, pero aplica el zoom al lugar que esta el cursor, antes en la v3 de d3.js se podia hacer como digo pero ahora la verdad que no se como hacer.

Comment: **pero** pon tu codigo para que podamos trabajar sobre él

Comment: @lois6bn editado, espero que podais ayudarme

Comment: Pon el html para que podamos probar una posible solución usando un snippet

Comment: Por favor, crea un [mcve] para que podamos ver tu código funcionando. He intentando poner tu JavaScript en JSFiddle, pero no consigo que funcione.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no es posible que te funcione en `JSFiddle` ya que tienen puesta la `v3` de `d3.js`.

Comment: @AndoniAlda estaba incluyendo d3 v4 como un archivo externo (se puede hacer en la parte izquierda de la pantalla )

Comment: @amenadiel Ya he editado la pregunta he incluido el html

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Vaya no sabia, que te da fallo exactamente? Puede que no haya incluido algun metodo que uso, puedo meter todo el script pero son unas cuantas lineas por eso solo inclui como hice el grafico y el zoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he conseguido hacerlo, hay que aplicar el estilo  `transform-origin","50% 50% 0"`

Ademas he añadido todos los elementos a un grupo padre para ahorrar lineas de codigo.

La funcion de zoom me ha quedado tal que asi:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()                            
                // Don’t allow the zoomed area to be bigger than the viewport.
                .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
                .translateExtent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
                .extent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
                .on("zoom", zoomed);                

        grupopadre.style("transform-origin", "50% 50% 0");               
            svg.call(zoom);
            function zoomed() {         
                grupopadre
                    .style('transform', 'scale(' + d3.event.transform.k + ')');
            }
```

De esta manera se aplica el zoom directamente al centro del grafico.

Si se necesita la posibilidad de moverte en el grafico y que el zoom centre solo el grafico cuando lo quitas hay que ponerlo asi:

```
    var zoom = d3.zoom()                            
        // Don’t allow the zoomed area to be bigger than the viewport.
        .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
        .translateExtent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
        .extent([[0, 0], [w, h]])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);                

    grupopadre.style("transform-origin", "50% 50% 0");

    svg.call(zoom);
    function zoomed() {         
        grupopadre.attr("transform",d3.event.transform);
    }
```